# Generating a .CSV with Several Columns - Use a Dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, set

I am writing a script that looks through my inventory, compares it with a master list of all possible inventory items, and tells me what items I am missing.  My goal is a .csv file where the first column contains a unique key integer and then the remaining several columns would have data related to that key.  For example, a three row snippet of my end-goal .csv file might look like this:

```
100001,apple,fruit,medium,12,red
100002,carrot,vegetable,medium,10,orange
100005,radish,vegetable,small,10,red
```

The data for this is being drawn from a couple sources.  1st, a query to an API server gives me a list of keys for items that are in inventory.  2nd, I read in a .csv file into a dict that matches keys with item name for all possible keys.  A snippet of the first 5 rows of this .csv file might look like this:

```
100001,apple
100002,carrot
100003,pear
100004,banana
100005,radish
```

Note how any key in my list of inventory will be found in this two column .csv file that gives all keys and their corresponding item name and this list minus my inventory on hand yields what I'm looking for (which is the inventory I need to get).

So far I can get a .csv file that contains just the keys and item names for the items that I don't have in inventory.  Give a list of inventory on hand like this:

```
100003,100004
```

A snippet of my resulting .csv file looks like this:

```
100001,apple
100002,carrot
100005,radish
```

This means that I have pear and banana in inventory (so they are not in this .csv file.)

To get this I have a function to get an item name when given an item id that looks like this:

```
def getNames(id_to_name, ids):
    return [id_to_name[id] for id in ids]
```

Then a function which gives a list of keys as integers from my inventory server API call that returns a list and I've run this function like this:

```
invlist = ServerApiCallFunction(AppropriateInfo)
```

A third function takes this invlist as its input and returns a dict of keys (the item id) and names for the items I don't have.  It also writes the information of this dict to a .csv file.  I am using the set1 - set2 method to do this.  It looks like this:

```
def InventoryNumbers(inventory):
    with open(csvfile,'w') as c:
        c.write('InvName' + ',InvID' + '\n')
    missinginvnames = []
    with open("KeyAndItemNameTwoColumns.csv","rb") as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
        fp.readline() # skip header
        invidsandnames = {int(id): str.upper(name) for id, name in reader}
    invids = set(invidsandnames.keys())
    invnames = set(invidsandnames.values())
    invonhandset = set(inventory)
    missinginvidsset = invids - invonhandset
    missinginvids = list(missinginvidsset)
    missinginvnames = getNames(invidsandnames, missinginvids)
    missinginvnameswithids = dict(zip(missinginvnames, missinginvids))
    print missinginvnameswithids
    with open(csvfile,'a') as c:
        for invname, invid in missinginvnameswithids.iteritems():
            c.write(invname + ',' + str(invid) + '\n')

    return missinginvnameswithids
```

Which I then call like this:

```
InventoryNumbers(invlist)
```

With that explanation, now on to my question here.  I want to expand the data in this output .csv file by adding in additional columns.  The data for this would be drawn from another .csv file, a snippet of which would look like this:

```
100001,fruit,medium,12,red
100002,vegetable,medium,10,orange
100003,fruit,medium,14,green
100004,fruit,medium,12,yellow
100005,vegetable,small,10,red
```

Note how this does not contain the item name (so I have to pull that from a different .csv file that just has the two columns of key and item name) but it does use the same keys.  I am looking for a way to bring in this extra information so that my final .csv file will not just tell me the keys (which are item ids) and item names for the items I don't have in stock but it will also have columns for type, size, number, and color.

One option I've looked at is the [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) piece from collections, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about what I want to do.  If I did use this method I'm not sure exactly how I'd call it to achieve my desired result.  If some other method would be easier I'm certainly willing to try that, too.

How can I take my dict of keys and corresponding item names for items that I don't have in inventory and add to it this extra information in such a way that I could output it all to a .csv file?

EDIT: As I typed this up it occurred to me that I might make things easier on myself by creating a new single .csv file that would have date in the form key,item name,type,size,number,color (basically just copying in the column for item name into the .csv that already has the other information for each key.)  This way I would only need to draw from one .csv file rather than from two.  Even if I did this, though, how would I go about making my desired .csv file based on only those keys for items not in inventory?

ANSWER: I posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294461/converting-dict-values-into-a-set-while-preserving-the-dict) about how to implement the solution I accepted (becauseit was giving me a value error since my dict values were strings rather than sets to start with) and I ended up deciding that I wanted a list rather than a set (to preserve the order.)  I also ended up adding the column with item names to my .csv file that had all the other data so that I only had to draw from one .csv file.  That said, here is what this section of code now looks like:

```
MyDict = {}
infile = open('FileWithAllTheData.csv', 'r')
for line in infile.readlines():
    spl_line = line.split(',')
    if int(spl_line[0]) in missinginvids: #note that this is the list I was using as the keys for my dict which I was zipping together with a corresponding list of item names to make my dict before.
        MyDict.setdefault(int(spl_line[0]), list()).append(spl_line[1:])
print MyDict
```

Comment: Coming from perl background and I am learning python. But your question looks perfectly suited for Perl. you can create a hash of the information that you want and then write that hash into the csv using just the print statement. Very simple. Apart from it, if you want to do something more advanced, then Text::CSV and DBD::CSV modules of perl will be way more than sufficient for your need. Perl is better known for string and text manipulation and i have played with the CSV files in perl numerous times. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Fair enough, and you might be right - Perl might be the better tool for this job.  For me, though, I know very little about programming and all I do know is in Python, so I think I'll stick with it.  That said, if someone else reads this and they are a more experienced programmer than I am, they probably should look into a Perl-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like what you need is a dict mapping ints to sets, ie,

`MyDict = {100001: set([apple]), 100002: set([carrot])}`

you can add with update:

`MyDict[100001].update([fruit])`

which would give you: `{100001: set([apple, fruit]), 100002: set([carrot])}`

Also if you had a list of attributes of carrot... `[vegetable,orange]`

you could say `MyDict[100002].update([vegetable, orange])`

and get: `{100001: set([apple, fruit]), 100002: set([carrot, vegetable, orange])}`

does this answer your question?

EDIT:

to read into CSV...

```
infile = open('MyFile.csv', 'r')
for line in infile.readlines():
    spl_line = line.split(',')
    if int(spl_line[0]) in MyDict.keys():
        MyDict[spl_line[0]].update(spl_line[1:])
```

Comment: We're getting close with that :)  The two questions it leaves are 1) How would I read in the data from the .csv file with the various data columns so that I would only be reading in the data for keys in MyDict 2) How do I then split these lists into pieces and make my final result .csv file?

Comment: The edit I made above will replace the current Dict line with whatever is in the file you are reading. As for writing out to a CSV, I think you can find answers to this if you dig around google.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!  Why the use of the dict.update rather than some sort of dict.extend or dict.append?  Doesn't update remove the previous data (so in my case it would remove the item name)? http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iteritem#dict.update

Comment: it would, another thing you could do is `MyDict[spl_line[0]].extend(spl_line[1:])`

Comment: I've updated this answer, a dict mapping ints to SETS is actually what you want

Comment: Alright, with the edit I see that you are still using .update - should the last line instead be like this (so that I don't lose the item name info already in the dict)? `MyDict[spl_line[0]].extend(spl_line[1:])`

Comment: `sets()` have the advantage of not allowing duplicates

Comment: double arrg, I did mean update, this won't get rid of past additions

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the question, but here is a possible way of simplifying your current code.

This:

```
invids = set(invidsandnames.keys())
invnames = set(invidsandnames.values())
invonhandset = set(inventory)
missinginvidsset = invids - invonhandset
missinginvids = list(missinginvidsset)
missinginvnames = getNames(invidsandnames, missinginvids)
missinginvnameswithids = dict(zip(missinginvnames, missinginvids))
```

Can be replaced with:

```
invonhandset = set(inventory)
missinginvnameswithids = {k: v for k, v in invidsandnames.iteritems() if k in in inventory}
```

Or:

```
invonhandset = set(inventory)
for key in invidsandnames.keys():
    if key not in invonhandset:
        del invidsandnames[key]
missinginvnameswithids = invidsandnames
```

Comment: I had messed with that style (using iteritems) and the set1 - set2 style and basically just went with the one that I managed to get to work first.  I'll look back over it and try the iteritems style again because it certainly is smaller and tidier.

Comment: It also doesn't require creating any intermediary sets. It should be much more efficient. I added another method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a temporary RDB (python has [sqlite support](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) baked in) and for reasonable numbers of items I don't think you would have a performance issues.

I would turn each CSV file and the result from the web-api into a tables (one table per data source). You can then do everything you want to do with some SQL queries + joins.  Once you have the data you want, you can then dump it back to CSV.

Comment: I'm certainly not against the idea - I don't really care what methods I need to use to get the desired .csv output - but I'm not sure what this would look like in this case.  I'll admit that part of why I've been using .csv files as inputs is to avoid SQL because I am not very familiar with it.  What might the needed queries (in Python) look like?

Comment: @Qanthelas python will basically pass the SQL queries directly to sqlite.  It is another can of worms, but I think one worth opening.